# How to enable CoreMotion in watchkit app?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, core-motion

[image]

I have 2 watchkit test apps that use CMPedometer and one of them is not accessing the CMPedometer. If I remember correctly, the one that works has called my iPhone with Access Your Motion & Fitness AlertView.

I receive this error:
Error Domain=CMErrorDomain Code=105

So how do I trigger that Alert again? 
Does anyone know how to properly authorize CoreMotion and Fitness to watchkit app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1.The first time an app queries the M7 the user is asked whether he wants to allow access. That's when this alert is shown.
You can delete your app,and build your app again.

2.If Settings->Privacy->Motion&Fitness->Fitness Tracking  is off ,your app wouldn't trigger any alert even in the first of build.You can change "*Fitness Tracking*" to On,and rebuild your app.

Comment: Only my watchkit app uses CoreMotion, but it is not authorized to retrieve stored motion data. The iPhone app does not use CoreMotion, so how do I request these permissions for the Apple watch?